# Feign and Ribbon [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service <Service_Name>]

Tags: spring-boot, ribbon, feign, openfeign, netflix-ribbon

In pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.khan.micro</groupId>
    <artifactId>currency-conversion-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>currency-conversion-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

in application.properties

```
spring.application.name=currency-conversion-service
server.port=8100
currency-exchange-service.ribbon.listOfServers=http://localhost:8000,http://localhost:8001
```

Main Class CurrencyConversionServiceApplication.java

```
package com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients("com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice")
public class CurrencyConversionServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CurrencyConversionServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy.java

```
package com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice;

import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

import com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice.contoller.bean.CurrencyConversionBean;

@FeignClient(name="currency-exchange-service")
@RibbonClient(name="currency-exchange-service")
public interface CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy {
    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
    public CurrencyConversionBean getExchangevalue(@PathVariable("from") String from, @PathVariable("to") String to);
}
```

CurrencyConvrterController. java

```
package com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice.contoller;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice.CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy;
import com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice.contoller.bean.CurrencyConversionBean;

@RestController
public class CurrencyConvrterController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy currencyExchangeServiceProxy;

    @GetMapping("/currency-converter/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    public CurrencyConversionBean getCurrencyConverted(@PathVariable String from, 
            @PathVariable String to, @PathVariable BigDecimal quantity) {
        
        Map<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        uriVariables.put("from", from);
        uriVariables.put("to", to);
        ResponseEntity<CurrencyConversionBean> responseEntity = new RestTemplate()
                .getForEntity("http://localhost:8000/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}", 
                CurrencyConversionBean.class, 
                uriVariables );
        CurrencyConversionBean response = responseEntity.getBody();
        return new CurrencyConversionBean(response.getId(), from, to, response.getConversionMultiple(), 
                response.getPort(), quantity, quantity.multiply(response.getConversionMultiple()));
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/currency-converter-feign/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    public CurrencyConversionBean getCurrencyConvertedFeign(@PathVariable String from, 
            @PathVariable String to, @PathVariable BigDecimal quantity) {
        CurrencyConversionBean response = currencyExchangeServiceProxy.getExchangevalue(from, to);
        return new CurrencyConversionBean(response.getId(), from, to, response.getConversionMultiple(), 
                response.getPort(), quantity, quantity.multiply(response.getConversionMultiple()));
    }
}
```

CurrencyConversionBean.java

```
package com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice.contoller.bean;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class CurrencyConversionBean {
    private Long id;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private BigDecimal conversionMultiple;
    private int port;
    private BigDecimal quantity;
    private BigDecimal totalCalculatedAmount;
    public CurrencyConversionBean() {
    }
    public CurrencyConversionBean(Long id, String from, String to, BigDecimal conversionMultiple, int port,
            BigDecimal quantity, BigDecimal totalCalculatedAmount) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.conversionMultiple = conversionMultiple;
        this.port = port;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.totalCalculatedAmount = totalCalculatedAmount;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
    public BigDecimal getConversionMultiple() {
        return conversionMultiple;
    }
    public void setConversionMultiple(BigDecimal conversionMultiple) {
        this.conversionMultiple = conversionMultiple;
    }
    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public BigDecimal getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    public void setQuantity(BigDecimal quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
    public BigDecimal getTotalCalculatedAmount() {
        return totalCalculatedAmount;
    }
    public void setTotalCalculatedAmount(BigDecimal totalCalculatedAmount) {
        this.totalCalculatedAmount = totalCalculatedAmount;
    }
    
}
```

while trying to access http://localhost:8100/currency-converter-feign/from/AUD/to/INR/quantity/1000 url getting given below error even if the both the currencyExchange Service are up and running on 8000 and 8001 ports

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Sep 18 02:46:01 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
[503] during [GET] to [http://currency-exchange-service/currency-exchange/from/AUD/to/INR] [CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy#getExchangevalue(String,String)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service currency-exchange-service]
feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [GET] to [http://currency-exchange-service/currency-exchange/from/AUD/to/INR] [CurrencyExchangeServiceProxy#getExchangevalue(String,String)]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service currency-exchange-service]
    at feign.FeignException.serverErrorStatus(FeignException.java:265)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:206)
    at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:194)
    at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:104)
    at feign.ResponseHandler.decodeError(ResponseHandler.java:136)
    at feign.ResponseHandler.handleResponse(ResponseHandler.java:70)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:114)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:70)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:96)
    at jdk.proxy6/jdk.proxy6.$Proxy113.getExchangevalue(Unknown Source)
    at com.khan.micro.currencyconversionservice.contoller.CurrencyConvrterController.getCurrencyConvertedFeign(CurrencyConvrterController.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

can anyone tell what could be the reason for this error is this the dependancies issue or what could be else will be here

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this config:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.currency-exchange-service[0].uri=http://localhost:8000
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.currency-exchange-service[1].uri=http://localhost:8001
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).